# usercontrol dissapears when using update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a user control which acts as a footer for my website and uses java script  jqdock.js to show  apple type bottom menu. I added an update panel to the usercontrol. What problem I am having now is, it works fine initally but once I click the mail button which is in the usercontrol , the whole user control dissapears, after postback i guess. below is the usercontrol and code view:

```
enter code here
```

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
   // Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("bottomMenu", "../js/jqDock.js");
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this,this.GetType(),"bottomMenu", "../js/jqDock.js");
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "bottomMenu", "../js/jqDock.js",true);
   }
```

//design view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucBottomMenu.ascx.cs"
Inherits="uc_ucBottomMenu" %>
<div id="dockWrapper" style="position: fixed; background: url('user/use.png');
padding: 10px; margin: 0 auto; width: 700px; height: 100px;" class="noprint">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="dock">

  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phEmail" runat="server"><a id="hplEmail" runat="server">
        <src="/dock/email.png" title="Email" alt="Email" /></a> </asp:PlaceHolder>



         </asp:PlaceHolder>


</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: sorry its  *<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phEmail" runat="server"><a id="hplEmail" runat="server">
            <img src="/dock/email.png" title="Email" alt="Email" /></a> </asp:PlaceHolder>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a startup script in your codebehind to call a function to re-initialize your jqDock.  This is becuase after the UpdatePanel postback, everything inside of `<ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>` gets replaced.

**Code-Behind:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), reInitjqDock, "reInitjqDock();", true);
```

**Script:**

```
//example
function reInitjqDock()
{
  jQuery('#dock').jqDock();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have the code commented out in your example.  Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead of ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude.

Comment: I do understand the theory behind it , but I dunno how to implement the above example , I am learning jquery . IT will be great if u can help me solve this step by step. like should I have to declare a function between content template and call that function code behind.. something like dat

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above code with no succes , the usercontrol dissapears after first click